# GCM : Unable to receive push notification in Android client

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

My Android client was unable to receive push notifications from GCM server even when `success:1`.
`multicast_id":8703499666074543637,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1439080356936445%9bd2607ff9fd7ecd"`

I followed this  [tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Cloud-Messaging) . It follows the new implemetation of using GCM where :

> 1. In the app manifest, replace your GcmBroadcastReceiver with "com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver", and replace the current service declaration that extends IntentService to >the new GcmListenerService
> 2. Remove the BroadcastReceiver implementation from your client code
> 3. Refactor the current IntentService service implementation to use GcmListenerService

I test my app for GCM push notifications using this  [link](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/gcm.html)  .

This is a part of my manifest for BroadcastReciever and IntentService:

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.usc.jay.ifff" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
       <service android:name="com.usc.jay.ifff.GCMIntentService"
        android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

My IntentService:

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GcmListenerService{
   public static final int MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 435345;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("message");

        sendNotification(message);
    }


    private void sendNotification(String message) {
        int icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = this.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("message", message);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

    }
```

Comment: You don't need `"com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"` in your GcmReceiver intent filter. Do messages get through to `onMessageReceived`?

Comment: i am facing same problem i have tried "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" too but it didn't worked can you please tell me what i am doing wrong ??

Comment: I believe that this is a device specific problem. I don't know but this code works on other devices like Samsung. I test it back on my previous device which did not receive any GCM notifications months ago, but right now it works perfectly on the said device.